# How can I check the file exists in Network UNC path in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a text box where the user can type the `UNC path` like `'\\server_name\testing\'`

How can I check this `UNC path` exists?

I have tried lot of options from the `File` and `Directory` and did not get any clue.

My current code is

```
def get_files(path)
  Dir.entries(path).select {|f| File.file?(f)}
end
```

When I tried to access `get_files('\\server_name\testing\')`. I got `No such file or directory - No such directory: \\server_name\testing\`

When I try to access through windows explorer it exists.

Thanks

Comment: `'\\'` is the escape sequence for a single backslash, you probably want `'\\\\'`

Comment: I have tried that as well. I got the same response.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your working directory is set properly, because your path will be considered relative to it. You can use `Dir.pwd` to get your working directory and `Dir.chdir` to change it.

Comment: Hi, Can you give some examples to change the directory to the `UNC` path like `\\server_name\testing` from my working directory path `'home/Documents/projects/'`

Answer (score 0):

`\\server_name\testing` is path to SAMBA resource, so you can't use standard ruby File IO.

Use [smbclient](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html) to check path or [sambal](https://github.com/johnae/sambal) (wrapper around `smbclient`).

Comment: Is it possible that we can check the path exists? and a file with specified extension exists and do other ruby stuffs with this gem files? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't have method such as `File#exists?` but you can use `ls` method to check file is exists or run `smbclient -L SERVERNAME | grep -i "YOURSHARENAME"`.

Comment: Thanks. My current working directory is `'home/Documents/projects/'`. So there is no other way that we can check the file path is correct and merge files from the path, etc., without using this gems?